# Polymer loop through an array of elements to be stamped

Tags: polymer

Is there anyway for me to do the following:

`<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[blocks]]">
  <[[item]]></[[item]]>
</template>`

using an array of elements such as: ['my-element1','my-element2','my-element3']

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot construct your tags in that way, however there's been this hack around for a while:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{blocks}}">
    <div inner-h-t-m-l={{item}}></div>
</template>
```

and have array contain:
`['<my-element1></my-element1>','<my-element2></my-element2>','<my-element3></my-element3>']`.

Although I'd rather avoid this method, because it hinders communication between elements and I would go with regular JS for element creation.

Comment: Would there be any possibility of me using <template is="my-element"> or is that not available?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what would you try to achieve with this.

Comment: Just like dom-if and dom-repeat are instantiated using the template is syntax, could I use that with any element? I found another way in the mean time. I created a custom element that takes a tag name as a property and imports/instantiates it at runtime.

Comment: I see, so you would like to use `<template is="{{item}}">` etc?
If you're using Polymer 2.0 the `template is` syntax is considered "legacy" and the only two whitelisted instances are `dom-if` and `dom-repeat`:
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/mixins/Polymer.TemplateStamp#method-_parseTemplateChildNodes

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'm almost done with the custom element that does what I want. I'll update you on the progress.

Comment: If you're interested here it is: https://github.com/anoblet/custom-element/blob/master/custom-element.html